# CALayerInvalid crash on resume

Tags: iphone, ios

I am seeing a CALayerInvalid crash every time my App resumes but only one a specific device. It's a 3rd Gen iPod Touch. Works fine on a 4th Gen or an iPad 1 or 2.

I've read some things about finding zombies but the debugger/instruments never seem to attach to the process earlier enough to detect the problem. I always see CALayerInvalid and it points to

```
retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MyAppDelegate class]));
```

I believe it is crashing while loading the XIB that is large and has a lot of content.

I'm not sure how to continue to debug the issue.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tracking this for a while I notice that it was only happening on low resolution screens.

I don't know why but the issue was solve by removing a window. I had accidentally set my view controllers view to a window. So it places a window in a window. Removing this removed the crash.